# Nginx wildcard reverse proxy to same name

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want nginx to take any requests from `*.example.com` and send them to the same name (`*.example.com`), just using nginx for SSL, and so that I can externally use my local DNS.

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     *.whitefamilyserver.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://$host; # (host will normally be subdomain.example.com)
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

So if someone went to `test.example.com`, it would forward it to `test.example.com` (but since this is running from inside my home network, it will use the local DNS to resolve the client).